# Linux Mint Cinnamon - AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter keeps on disconnecting

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, cinnamon

I have a DELL inspiron 15-3521 running the latest version of Linux Mint Cinnamon. When booting my PC everything works perfectly for about 10 to 30 minutes, after that the wireless network gets disconnected. I am unable to reconnect until unless I restart my PC. I tried disabling enabling my network but with no result. Any ideas on how to solve this?

My Ethernet card is:

```
Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having a similar problem :(

Comment: @pietrovismara no, I have been using ubuntu. Try to restarting the network manager from the terminal.